# python Mysql.connector doesn´t connect BUT mysql server is up and working

Tags: docker, mysql-connector-python

This is the docker-compose file

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'bot'
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: '123'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
    volumes:
      - mybot:/var/lib/mysql
  
  python:    
    restart: always
    build: .
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'bot'
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: '123'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
    volumes:
      - mybot:/usr/app
    command: tail -f /dev/null
volumes:
  mybot:
```

and Dockerfile

```
FROM python

user root
WORKDIR /usr/src
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN mkdir -p new
COPY . ./new
```

Now, when I run sh terminal from python container, i had access to mysql database without problem (before that i manually installed default-mysql-server)

```
mysql -u user -p -u 172.X.X.X
mysql>
```

and also i am able to ping between containers with no errors, BUT when I run main.py I get the following error

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at '172.X.X.X:3306', system error: 1 [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:1123)
```

main.py is connecting to mysql like this

```
self.mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host=params["host"],
                                            user=params["user"],
                                            password=params["pass"],
                                            database=params["database"])
```

and mysql my.cnf file has this custom lines

```
port = 3306
bind-address = 172.X.X.X
```

"outside" docker containers, everything works great..
Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the mysql-connector that occurs in some versions.
The easiest way to workaround this is to switch to pymysql

Install pymysql

```
pip install pymysql
```

Simple select example:

```
import pymysql

connection = pymysql.connect(user='user', passwd='pass', host='host', database='database')
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = ("SELECT * FROM myTable")
cursor.execute(query)
for item in cursor:
    print item
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tested with the above Docker configuration and I was able to connect:

```
root@bf838ebaa060:/usr/src# pip list
Package                Version
---------------------- -------
mysql-connector-python 8.0.21
pip                    20.1.1
protobuf               3.12.2
setuptools             49.2.0
six                    1.15.0
wheel                  0.34.2

root@bf838ebaa060:/usr/src# cat test.py
import mysql.connector

config = {
    "host": "172.x.x.x",
    "port": 3306,
    "user": "root",
    "password": "root"
}

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
cur = cnx.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT VERSION()")
res = cur.fetchone()
print(res)
cur.close()
cnx.close()

root@bf838ebaa060:/usr/src# python test.py
('8.0.21',)
```

Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of MySQL Connector/Python. Please let me know if it still doesn't work for you.

Comment: That configuration works and give the same output, but using an older version of MySQL connector python give me the same error as before:
```Package                Version
---------------------- -------
mysql-connector-python 8.0.5
pip                    20.1.1
protobuf               3.12.2
setuptools             49.2.0
six                    1.15.0
wheel                  0.34.2
```

Thanks for your help! tell me if something is needed!

Comment: Version 8.0.5 is quite old, please upgrade (if you can). The latest release contains lots of improvements and bug fixes.

Comment: This was it, upgrading to latest version fixed the issue for me